# Javaの文字列の比較について

Tags: java

[Aizu Online ジャッジの問題](http://judge.u-aizu.ac.jp/onlinejudge/description.jsp?id=ITP1_4_C)を解いているのですが、以下のプログラムの間違っている箇所を教えてください。

`+-*/?`をString型のString cに代入して、`if(c=="+")`のように条件分岐させているのですが、うまくいっていないようです。

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try{
      while(true){
        String str = reader.readLine();

        String[] str_Array = str.split(" ");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(str_Array[0]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(str_Array[2]);
        String c = str_Array[1];
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);

        if(c == "?") break;
        if(c == "+"){
          System.out.println(a+b);
        }else if(c == "-"){
          System.out.println(a-b);
        }else if(c == "/"){
          System.out.println(a/b);
        }else if(c == "*"){
          System.out.println(a*b);
        }
      }
      reader.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
      System.out.println("エラー:"+e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

文字列の比較には`==`ではなく、`equals()`を使いましょう。

```
if(c.equals("?")) break;
```

のような感じです。

`==` は、同じオブジェクトであるかどうかを判定するときに使います。一方、`equals()` は、同じ値であるかどうかを判定するときに使います。`equals()` の場合は、違うオブジェクトの比較であっても、保持している値が同じ場合は`true`を返します。

例えば、

```
public class EqualsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "boo";
        String s2 = s1;
        System.out.println(s1==s2);         // true
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));  // true

        String s3 = new String(s1);
        System.out.println(s1==s3);         // false
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s3));  // true
    }
}
```

というコードでは、`s1`と`s2`は同じオブジェクトを指しているので`==`でも`equals()`でも`true`を返します。
`s3`は、`s1`を元にして別のオブジェクトを新しく生成しています。つまり、値が同じ別のオブジェクトなので、`==`は`false`を、`equals()`は`true`を返します。