# 変数が"-"と等しいかを判定する方法

Tags: java

Javaのプログラムで"-"(ハイフン)が入力されたたときにループを終了するプログラムを作りたいのですが、どのようにすればいいでしょうか。

```
        while(true){
            str=reader.readLine();

            if(str.equals("\\-"))break;
            //以下省略
        }
```

このように作ったのですが、"-"が認識されずループを終えることができません。

Comment: [以前](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/24297/java%E3%81%AE%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%81%AE%E6%AF%94%E8%BC%83%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)に経験済み

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この場合単に文字列の等値判定ですので、エスケープ文字を前に付ける必要はありません。

例： `if(str.equals("-"))break;`

Comment: `str`が`null`って事はないのでしょうか？

Comment: @mjy  入力次第だと思います。もし`null`の場合は例外を起こすでしょうから、これ以前にチェックすべきなのかもしれません。それは実際の入力とプログラマが何を想定するかによると思います。