# for文の中でbreakが機能しません。どうしてでしょうか？

Tags: java

以下のプログラムで、breakが機能しません。
プログラムの意図としては、「もし0を入力したら、for文を抜ける」というものです。正常に記述しましたが、0を入れても、for文が回ります。どうしてでしょうか？

```java
//package j2.lesson01;
import java.util.*;
public class AverageClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // 国語の点数記録を作る
        // (CourseRecord型のデータを一つ作り、そのIDをcr0に格納する)
        CourseRecord cr0 = new CourseRecord();
        cr0.subject = "国語";
        cr0.score = 55;

        // 数学の点数記録を作る
        CourseRecord cr1 = new CourseRecord();
         cr1.subject = "数学";
         cr1.score = 95;

        // 英語の点数記録を作る
        CourseRecord cr2 = new CourseRecord();
          cr2.subject = "英語";
          cr2.score = 78;

        // 平均点
        double average = (cr0.score + cr1.score + cr2.score) / 3.0;

        // それぞれの科目について表示する
        System.out.println(cr0.subject + "の得点は" + cr0.score + "点");
        System.out.println(cr1.subject + "の得点は" + cr1.score + "点");
        System.out.println(cr2.subject + "の得点は" + cr2.score + "点");

        // 平均点を表示
        System.out.println("平均点は" + average + "点");

        Idai a = new Idai("あいう",18);
        a.print();
        Idai b = new Idai("かきく");
        b.print();
        for (int i=0;i<20;++i){
        System.out.print("文字を入れてください>");
        String c = sc.nextLine();
        if(c=="0"){
            //int a = Integer.parseInt(c);
            break;}
        Idai d = new Idai(c);
        d.print3(); 
        }
    }

    static class CourseRecord {

        // 科目名
        String subject;

        // 点数
        int score;

    }

   static class Idai{

    String str;
    int x;
    Idai(String str,int x){this.str=str;this.x=x;}
    Idai(String str){this.str=str;}

    public void print(){System.out.println(str+x);}
    //public void print2(){System.out.println(str);}
    public void print3(){System.out.println("任意の入力文字は"+str);}

   }

}
```

実行結果は以下の通りです。

```
国語の得点は55点
数学の得点は95点
英語の得点は78点
平均点は76.0点
あいう18
かきく0
文字を入れてください>0
任意の入力文字は0
文字を入れてください>０
任意の入力文字は０
文字を入れてください>0
任意の入力文字は0
文字を入れてください>0
任意の入力文字は0
文字を入れてください>0
任意の入力文字は0
文字を入れてください>
```

Comment: [こちらのスレッド](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/24297/13972)で質問されているのと同じ内容のようです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java で文字列の比較をするには `String` クラスの `equals()` メソッドを使う必要があります。つまり、

```
c=="0"
```

の代わりに

```
c.equals("0")
```

と書く必要があります。

`==` を使う比較はオブジェクト同士のポインタ比較になりますので、文字列の中身が一緒であっても違うオブジェクトであれば `false` が返ってきてしまいます。

Answer (score 0):

breakが機能しない、のではなく、breakが実行されてないんじゃないでしょうか。

> if(c=="0"){

これは成立しません